# Issue with Django Login Form

Tags: python, django

i am learning to customize django login forms. But here i am facing some weired issues. Like when i am trying to login but shows an error "Enter a valid email address"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rAJX.png)
Can anyone tell me which one actually causing this problem?

Forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django import forms

class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

username = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Username', 'id': 'hello'}))
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
    attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Enter your Password',
    }
))
```

Urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from . import views
from .forms import UserLoginForm
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeView, name='index'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name="registration/login.html", authentication_form=UserLoginForm),  name='login'),
    path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('authuser/', views.userView, name='authuser'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'), name='logout')

]
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<h3>This is login page</h3>

<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ form.username }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.password }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.username.errors }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.password.errors }}</p>


    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Log in">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .forms import UserLoginForm


def HomeView(request):
    return render(request,"index.html")

def userView(request):
    return render(request,"user.html")

class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name="about.html"
```

Comment: You used a `forms.EmailField`, hence you ask the form to validate if the user enters a valid email address for `username`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your forms your username is EmailField, the Django automatically validates the input as email, so when the username is not valid email, it throws the error. Try to change it to CharField for example